# Populating a Spinner in AlertDialog

Tags: android, spinner, android-alertdialog

I am trying to populate a spinner in an AlertDialog using the following code:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, providersList);

    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    AlertDialog.Builder checkInDialog1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 
    checkInDialog1.setView(R.layout.layout_checkin_items);

    checkInDialog1.show();
    AlertDialog builder = checkInDialog1.create();
    Spinner checkInProviders = (Spinner) builder.findViewById(R.id.providers);
    checkInProviders.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

But builder.findViewById is returning null for checkInProviders.

In my XML:

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/providers"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: you need just spinner right in popup ??

Comment: Try to inflate your view :
    AlertDialog.Builder checkInDialog1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    View dialogView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.layout_checkin_items, null);
    checkInDialog1.setView(dialogView);
    Spinner checkInProviders = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.providers);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try this

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
final View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_checkin_items, null);
dialogBuilder.setView(myView);    
Spinner checkInProviders = (Spinner) myView .findViewById(R.id.providers);
 ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, providersList);

dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
checkInProviders.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

> Try this

```
Dialog dialog=new Dialog(this);
dialog.setTitle("Title");     
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_checkin_items); 
Spinner checkInProviders = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.providers);
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, providersList);

dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
checkInProviders.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

dialog.show();
```

Comment: @AlanFirblazer happy to help you brother

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not inflating the view

> View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_checkin_items, null);

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_checkin_items, null);
dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

Spinner checkInProviders = (Spinner) dialogView .findViewById(R.id.providers);
```

In the bottom only add

> AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
>
> ```
> b.show();
> ```